# how to delete rows in a single table involving multiple table

Tags: mysql

hi i'm just new to sql and i have a hard time deleting records. i need to   Delete all the records from subjcode table where the teacher is “MARSHALL”. i used this query but i doesn't work:

```
delete
from subjcode
where (
        select sa.sno
        from subjcode sa,
            teacher,
            course
        where teacher.tname = 'MARSHALL'
            and teacher.tno = course.tno
            and course.cno = sa.cno
        ) = subjcode.sno;
```

and there is the table and its columns:

```
subjcode: sno,cno,score

course: cno,tno,cname

teacher:tno,tname
```

i know that all i need is just the tname,tno, and the cno but i don't know the proper query. please help me thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
delete s 
from subjcode s 
join course c on s.cno = c.cno 
join teacher t on c.tno = t.tno
where t.tname = 'MARSHALL';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete using join:

```
delete s
from subjcode s
join course c on s.cno = c.cno
join teacher t on t.tno = c.tno
where t.tname = 'MARSHALL';
```

See this for reference:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Comment: Applause for the reference, but apart from this your answer is literally exactly the same as mine :-)

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis - Yes. I didn't see your answer until I posted mine.